# My node.js app is running, but cannot access it through servers ip

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean

I have an app that is running on host: http://localhost:1111, when I try to access it through my server ip as follow: xxx.xx.xxx.xx:1111 it is not showing anything. When I run my app on my local pc it is running perfectly good

I tried to open ports, ping the ip with the port

Comment: `ping the ip with the port` what do you mean by this?

Comment: in the terminal: ping xxx.xx.xxx.xx:1111

Comment: I think you cannot `ping by port` and open it, try running `sudo iptables -L` in the server terminal and post the output

Comment: as it is too long for a comment I uploaded it here [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/16a5d74accf759b0b2182b50b5d392f820190523093708/ba6103)

Comment: Seems like there is no filters from the iptables which block the connection. verify user server is running by running `netstat -anp | grep 1111 | grep LISTEN` and check  if there is something like `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      - `

Comment: @MarcipanRebaru are you using a cloud firewall?